# How to automate StackApp user approve and user login with stack Exchange explicit oAuth2.0

Tags: support, api-v2.2, oauth2, stackapps

We are developing an stack App and integrating the app in our application. However we have successfully done a POC over POSTMAN and fiddler for explicit oAuth2.0. Now when we are integrating the same in our app,
while generating the access_code through application
we are hitting this endpoint

```
https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=1xx6&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net&client_secret=b*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx((&state=optional
```

in the response we are getting an login page for stackoverflow, As we know it will ask for username & password. How we can automate the stackOverflow login so we can get the access code and call the stackExchange API.

Any help on this will be appreciated...
As this is a blocker for us.